# Audio for Windows in Assembly

Tags: windows, audio, assembly, x86-16

I'm thinking of making a game in 8086 ASM using VGA for graphics, but before I proceed with anything I want to make sure that I can get audio into my project. I doubt PC Speaker will be sufficient.

I'm looking for a way to program music in 8086 for Windows. Is there some kind of standard in modern sound cards that I can access directly, or will I have to use the Windows API? I'm not really sure what to look for at this point, so any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: If you want to directly access the hardware you'll have to boot into DOS (or similar) or run your program in an emulator like DOSBox.  DOSBox supports SoundBlaster emulation (SoundBlaster was a popular sound card in days of yore).  If you target VGA and SoundBlaster and run in DOSBox your program should work.

Comment: Which Windows version[s] you are targeting? At least in older real mode Windows versions (up to 3.0) you can write directly to eg. Sound Blaster and Gravis Ultrasound ports, but I don't know about newer versions. Based on the 8086 flag, you seem to target Windows versions from 1.0 to 3.0. Windows versions from 3.1 run only in protected mode and thus require 286 or newer processor. Use `x86` tag if you mean the general Intel x86 architecture. `8086` tag refers specifically to 8086.

Comment: That could work, but I was hoping for a way to run it without emulation on a modern machine. So yes, nrz, I suppose I do mean x86 in a way, though I will be using 8086 (I'm pretty sure it'll run, since it's the same architecture, right?).

By the sound of it, I won't really be able to program audio directly in ASM if I want to run it on modern machines, right?

Comment: You can use DosBox in newer machines too, it should work. So you can write eg. a DOS program in assembly targeted to 8088/8086, 286 or 386 (with HIMEM.SYS in DOS, 32-bit addressing and 32-bit registers in general make your life a lot easier, should work in DosBox) and then run it in DosBox. I don't have a Windows machine to test, but at least in Linux DosBox DOS programs written in asm for DOS with HIMEM.SYS environment work. In an protected mode OS you usually cannot write and read ports directly in an userland application. See http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2008/readings/i386/s08_03.htm .

Comment: Yes.  If you want to run without emulation (or a virtual machine) and you want to access hardware directly you'll have to boot your PC into an ancient OS like DOS.

Comment: Ah, I was afraid of that. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4):

Unlike the displays, which ultimately converged to (S)VGA, soundcards never reached the same compatibility. There were different Sound Blasters, Gravis Ultrasound and others. These days the modern hardware is often incompatible with those and you cannot program them in DOS as the Sound Blaster without having a proper DOS driver or without knowing the supported memory regions, ports, formats and protocols.

I can only suggest writing such a program for a PC/DOS emulator like DosBox, which emulates Sound Blaster and (S)VGA. That should work.

Alternatively, you can just write a normal Windows program, using Win32 APIs for input, drawing and sound.